# The integral solution of $x^{2}-y^{3}=1 (x>1,y>1) $?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I know it's a special case of catalan's conjecture.Wiki says its only solution is $(3,2)$.But I cannot work  it out.Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: @Tree23- I feel like proving this is much easier than proving the Catalan conjecture. You just have to do trivial analysis, and not worry about the kind of math involved in proving the Catalan conjecture

Answer (score 2):

You can re-write the expression as $y^3=x^2-1=(x+1)(x-1)$. Now we can do some analysis. The only common factor that $x+1$ and $x-1$ can have is $2$.

1. Case 1- They have no common factor. In that case, both $x+1$ and $x-1$ are cubes. This is impossible, as the smallest difference between cubes is $2^3-1^3=7$.
2. Case 2- They have one common factor- namely $2$. Then for $(x-1)(x+1)$ to be a cube, $x-1=2a^3$ and $x+1=2^2b^3$, or $x-1=2^2a^3$ and $x+1=2b^3$. Here $a,b$ are positive numbers different from $2$. Hence, $|2a^3-2^2b^3|=2$ or $|2^2a^3-2b^3|=2$. We can now see that the only way that this is possible is that $a=b=1$.

Hence, $x=3, y=2$ is the only solution

Comment: In case 2 won't one of the two factors be $4$ times a cube? Otherwise their product is not a cube.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen- Yes I have now edited the answer.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen- both $x,y>1$. I have also now edited the answer

Comment: And *how* can we see that e.g. $|a^3-2b^3|=1$ is only possible with $a=b=1$?

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for some specific solution? Do you mean $3^2-2^3=9-8=1$?

Comment: Sorry I just forgot to say that Wiki said its only solution with$x,y>1$ is$(3,2)$.I don't know how to prove it.

Answer (score 0):

Not finished!

Write $$(x-1)(x+1)=y^3$$

**Case 1**. $x$ is even then $x+1$ and $x-1$ are relatively prime so $$ x-1 = a^3$$  $$x+1 = b^3$$ where $a<b$ are relatively prime and $ab=y$. Now we have $$2=(b-a)(b^2+ab+a^2)$$
and so:

- $b-a=1$ and $b^2+ab+a^2 =2$ so $$ 3a^2+3a+1 =2$$ and this is impossibile.
- $b-a=2$ and $b^2+ab+a^2 =1$ so $$ 3a^2+6a+4=1$$ so $a=-1$ and $b=1$ so $y=-2$ and $x=0$ whivh is not ok again.

**Case 2**. $x=2z+1$ then $y=2t$ so $$z(z+1)=2t^3$$
Since $z,z+1$ are relatively prime we have

- $z=2a^3$ and $z+1=b^3$, so $2a^3=b^3-1= (b-1)(b^2+b+1)$. So $$b-1 = 2p^3$$ $$b^2+b+1=q^3$$ where $p,q$ are relatively prime...
- $z=a^3$ and $z+1=2b^3$, so $2b^3= a^3+1=(a+1)(a^2-a+1)$. So $$a+1 = 2p^3$$ $$a^2-a+1=q^3$$ where $p,q$ are relatively prime...